# Counting number of rows by class starting with an upper case word

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to count the rows which starts with an upper case word (e.g. STACKOVERFLOW) by class.
To find an upper case word I am using the following line of code:

```
df['UP'] = df['TEST'].str.findall(r'\b([A-Z]{2,})')
```

I think I should consider something like this [1] (first word).

My dataset looks like:

```
TEST                       Class
HELLOOOOO!!!                1    
What are you doing?         0     # since this is only a capital letter, this should not be counted
Say nothing!                1     # since this is only a capital letter, this should not be counted
How are you?                0     # since this is only a capital letter, this should not be counted
HI man                      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex pattern is going to fail if you have a word with two capital letters but the rest are lowercase. This might help.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'TEST': {0: 'HELLOOOOO!!!',
  1: 'WHat are you doing?',
  2: 'Say nothing!',
  3: 'How are you?',
  4: 'HI man'},
 'Class': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 1}})

df['Upper'] = df['TEST'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0].isupper())

df.groupby('Class')['Upper'].sum()
```

Output

```
Class
0    0
1    2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. If I wanted to have instead of True/False, the word which is upper, may I use df['Upper'] = df['TEST'].str.findall(r'\b([A-Z]{2,})')? I think I should add something that selects at this point only the first word within the row (as you mentioned in your answer)

Comment: Just remove the `.isupper()` part.  it's already only looking at the first word per row.  This will of course break the final calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Lets Try extract first two capital letters, find where there is no NaN returned and convert it into an interger.

```
df['Class']=df.TEST.str.extract('(^[A-Z]{2})').notna().astype(int)
```